# Loading Parent and Child

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I"m trying to accomplish loading parent and children in one go. My query is this:

```
  ISearchResponse<Models.Facilities.Facility> response = await this._elasticClient.SearchAsync<Models.Facilities.Facility>(s =>
            s.Query(q => (q.GeoDistance(g => g.Boost(1.1)
                                     .Field(f => f.BusinessLocation)
                                     .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc)
                                     .Distance(search.location.distance.ToString() + "m")
                                     .Location((double)search.location.latitude, (double)search.location.longitude)
                       )
                       &&
                       q.HasChild<Models.Facilities.FacilityType>(c => c.Query(qq => qq.MatchAll()).Name("FacilityType")))
                       || 
                       q.GeoDistance(g => g.Boost(1.1)
                            .Field(f => f.ServiceAreas)
                            .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc)
                             .Distance(search.location.distance.ToString() + "m")
                            .Location((double)search.location.latitude, (double)search.location.longitude))

             )


            .Aggregations(a =>
                         a.Children<Models.Facilities.FacilityType>("Capacity", child => child.Aggregations(ca => ca.Histogram("Capacity",
                             h => h.Field(p => p.Capacity)
                                   .Interval(10)
                                   .Missing(0))))
                         .Histogram("Distance", d => d.Field(f => f.BusinessLocation)
                                                       .Interval(10)
                                                       .Order(HistogramOrder.CountDescending)))
              .Sort(g => g.GeoDistance(g => g.Field(f => f.BusinessLocation)
              .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc)
              .Order(SortOrder.Descending)
              .Unit(DistanceUnit.Miles)).GeoDistance(g => g.Field(f => f.ServiceAreas)
                .DistanceType(GeoDistanceType.Arc)
                .Order(SortOrder.Descending))));
```

*Facility* and *FacilityType* extends from a parent *Document*. I'm trying to load the parent `Facility` along with its children `FacilityType`. Essentially if I could achieve an object like this `facilityObj.facilityTypes`. Let me know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

InnerHits works for both Nested and Parent/Child relationships.